# Angular Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'XModule')

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

In my Angular 2 app, I have a `OverlayService`:

```
@Injectable()
export class OverlayService {

 showDialog() {
  this.cmpRef = DialogComponent;
 }

}
```

`DialogComponent` html is like this :

```
<div app-config-handler> </div>
```

and also the component have it's own `DialogModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [DialogComponent],
  exports: [DialogComponent],
  imports: [ConfigHandlerModule] // to use directive
})
export class DialogModule {
}
```

next, `ConfigHandlerDirective`:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[app-config-handler]' })
export class ConfigHandlerDirective {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {
  }
}
```

and when the app runs, cause the error:
`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ConfigHandlerModule')`

`OverlayService` and `ConfigService` both are provided in a `coreModule` that imported in the `AppModule`.

What have I tried:

- provide `OverlayService` and `ConfigService` in `root` (in their @Injectable decorator)
- make `ConfigHandlerDirective` as a standalone directive

but the error was exist.

But when I

1. remove `ConfigHandlerModule` from `DialogModule` or
2. remove `ConfigService` from `ConfigHandlerDirective` or
3. remove usage of `DialogComponent` in `OverlayService`

the error is fixes.

Do you have an idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: There are essential parts of your code missing in the question to be able to help you. What does your `ConfigHandlerModule` look like? Did you import the file inside the component?

Comment: @Wilt Your right but the main dependencies is betwenn these files. `ConfigHandlerModule` just declare and export the `ConfigHandlerDirective`.  And it imported inside `DialogModule` (code above).